# Using a ruby gem to discern whether a tweet is positive or not using Data mining or NLP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, machine-learning, classification, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a project for fun to discern whether tweets about a topic are positive or not. I've been looking for gems about machine learning and NLP and I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for. This one looks promising (https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp) as well as (https://github.com/SergioFierens/ai4r) Any suggestions for a good gem, or how to get started implementing this? I'm feeling a bit lost.

Comment: The Stanford Core NLP is a beast that can be used for different NLP tasks. Note that it depends on having access to Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn: https://github.com/arbox/nlp-with-ruby

If you need to train your own classifier (meaning you have data to train): https://srug.pl/assets/mateusz-drozdzynski-sentiment-analysis-in-ruby.pdf

If you just want something that works: https://github.com/7compass/sentimental